localhost redirection on port 443 fails from inside docker container
Might be a long question, i tried my best to be as explanatory as possible.
I had one node express application running on port 3000 and that application was consuming one remote webservice (example.com) for which i have set port forwarding using aws ssm (aws session manager).
So my aws ssm command looked like :
aws ssm start-session --target i-123456abcdef12345 --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSession --parameters "portNumber"=["33344"],"localPortNumber"=["443"] --region eu-central-1

After starting the aws session i did configure the localhost redirection via hosts file like so :
127.0.0.1 example.com

It worked perfectly.
I am now trying to dockerize it.
I want to setup this docker itself and start aws ssm inside the container.
For that i have tried and my docker-compose and Dockerfile looks like below, i also use one docker-compose for development purposes :
Dockerfile:

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/test-app && chown -R node:node /usr/src/test-app

USER root
# Install AWS CLI
RUN apk --no-cache update && \
    apk --no-cache add curl && \
    curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" && \
    unzip awscliv2.zip && \
    ./aws/install && \
    rm -rf aws awscliv2.zip \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/bin/aws \
    && chown -R node:node /usr/local/aws-cli/v2 \
    && chmod -R 777 /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/bin/aws 

# Add AWS CLI executable to PATH
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/aws-cli/v2/bin/aws"


# Set AWS configuration and credentials
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
ENV AWS_REGION=${AWS_REGION}
ENV AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}

USER node

WORKDIR /usr/src/test-app

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install --pure-lockfile

COPY --chown=node:node . .

EXPOSE 3000


docker-compose :
version: '3'

services:
  test-app:
    build:
      context: .
    image: test-app
    environment:
      - MONGODB_URL=mongodb://mongodb:27017/test
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
      - AWS_REGION=${AWS_REGION}
      - AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/test-app
    networks:
      - test-network

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.2.1-bionic
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/data/db
    networks:
      - test-network

volumes:
  dbdata:


networks:
  test-network:
    driver: bridge

docker-compose.dev.yml :
version: '3'

services:
  test-app:
    container_name: test-app-dev
    command: >
      sh -c "aws configure set aws_access_key_id ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} &&
             aws configure set aws_secret_access_key ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY} &&
             aws configure set aws_session_token ${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN} &&
             aws configure set region ${AWS_REGION} &&
             aws ssm start-session --target i-123456abcdef12345 --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSession --parameters \"portNumber\"=[\"33344\"],\"localPortNumber\"=[\"443\"] --region ${AWS_REGION} &&
             sleep 10 &&
             yarn dev -L"

Scripts in my package.json :
 "scripts": {
    "docker:dev": "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up"
  },

In my package.json i use npm script to compose the docker containers and utilize docker-compose.dev.yml to pass some additional arguments to start the app for development purposes.
My goal is to first start aws session via aws ssm inside container and then run node app on port 3000. Do i need to expose port 443 in docker-compose also ?
The node app utilizes a remote webservice on port 443 for which i need a port forwarding and my remote call should go to port 33344 on remote service.
So node app runs inside container port 3000, node app calls remote webservice on port 443 and there's port forwarding from container port 443 to remote port 33344 using aws ssm.
I am getting below error :
tes-app-dev    | sh: aws: not found
test-app-dev exited with code 127


Could you try to replace ENV PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/aws-cli/v2/bin/aws" by ENV PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/aws-cli/v2/bin/"

...because $PATH is a list of directories, not individual programs.
